# Leaky ReLU in Hyperparameter optimization Python not found

Tags: python, keras, hyperparameters, activation

I am using a dictionary of hyparameters and a function for hyperparameter optimization in Neural Networks which looks like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU

parameters=[
    {
        "name": "learning_rate",
        "type": "range",
        "bounds": [0.001, 0.5],
        "log_scale": True,
    },
    {
        "name": "dropout_rate",
        "type": "range",
        "bounds": [0.01, 0.9],
        "log_scale": True,
    },
    {
        "name": "num_hidden_layers",
        "type": "range",
        "bounds": [1, 7],
        "value_type": "int"
    },
    {
        "name": "neurons_per_layer",
        "type": "range",
        "bounds": [1, 300],
        "value_type": "int"
    },
    {
        "name": "batch_size",
        "type": "choice",
        "values": [8, 10, 16, 20, 30],
    },
    
    {
        "name": "activation",
        "type": "choice",
        "values": [ 'LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)', 'relu'],
    },
    {
        "name": "optimizer",
        "type": "choice",
        "values": ['adam', 'rms', 'sgd'],
    },
]

# This returns a multi-layer-perceptron model in Keras.
def get_keras_model(num_hidden_layers, 
                    num_neurons_per_layer, 
                    dropout_rate, 
                    activation):
    # create the MLP model.
    
    # define the layers.
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(train_dataset.shape[1],))  # input layer.
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(inputs) # dropout on the weights.
    
    # Add the hidden layers.
    for i in range(num_hidden_layers):
        x = layers.Dense(num_neurons_per_layer, 
                         activation=activation)(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    
    # output layer.
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model
    

# This function takes in the hyperparameters and returns a score (Cross validation). 
# Returns the mean of the validation loss based on which we decide which algorithm has the best hyperparameters
def keras_mlp_cv_score(parameterization, weight=None):
    
    model = get_keras_model(parameterization.get('num_hidden_layers'),
                            parameterization.get('neurons_per_layer'),
                            parameterization.get('dropout_rate'),
                            parameterization.get('activation'))
    
    opt = parameterization.get('optimizer')
    opt = opt.lower()
    
    learning_rate = parameterization.get('learning_rate')
    
    if opt == 'adam':
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    elif opt == 'rms':
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    else:
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        
    act = parameterization.get('activation')
    act = act.lower()
    
    if act == 'leakyrelu': 
        activation = ""
        get_keras_model.add(tf.layers.leakyReLU())
    
    
    NUM_EPOCHS = 100
    
    # Specify the training configuration.
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                  metrics=['mae', 'mse'] )

    data = X_train
    labels = y_train.values
    
    early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)

    
    # fit the model using a 20% validation set. with a patience of 10 to avoid overfitting
    res = model.fit(data, labels, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, batch_size=parameterization.get('batch_size'),
                    validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stop, tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()])
    
    # look at the last 10 epochs. Get the mean and standard deviation of the validation score.
    last10_scores = np.array(res.history['val_loss'][-10:])
    mean = last10_scores.mean()
    sem = last10_scores.std()
    
    # If the model didn't converge then set a high loss.
    if np.isnan(mean):
        return 9999.0, 0.0
    
    return mean, sem
```

But no matter how I use LeakyReLU, it throws the error that the activation function is not found.  I also tried `tf.nn.leaky_relu`
Please help me in incorporating LeakyReLU properly in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote :

```
act = act.lower()    

if act == 'LeakyReLU': 
    ...
```

This test will always be false because `'LeakyReLU'` has some capital letters and `act` never does, therefore it will never add a LeakyRelu layer to your model.

Try:

```
act = act.lower()    

if act == 'leakyrelu': 
    ...
```

Also, the correct syntax is `tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()` ([Leaky ReLU in tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LeakyReLU)).

If needed, please update your question with the stacktrace of the error.

Please try this :

```
def get_keras_model(num_hidden_layers, 
                num_neurons_per_layer, 
                dropout_rate, 
                activation):
    # create the MLP model.

    # define the layers.
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(train_dataset.shape[1],))  # input layer.
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(inputs) # dropout on the weights.

    leakyrelu =  activation.lower() == 'leakyrelu'

    # Add the hidden layers.
    for i in range(num_hidden_layers):
        x = layers.Dense(num_neurons_per_layer, 
                     activation=activation if not leakyrelu else None)(x)
        if leakyrelu:
            x = LeakyReLU()(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)    


def keras_mlp_cv_score(parameterization, weight=None):

    model = get_keras_model(parameterization.get('num_hidden_layers'),
                        parameterization.get('neurons_per_layer'),
                        parameterization.get('dropout_rate'),
                        parameterization.get('activation'))

    # No need for "if act == 'leakyrelu':" etc anymore.
....
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake, I corrected it and reran the code, the error still lingers. Can you please suggest anything else that could be wrong? @Whole Brain

Comment: Yes. You already imported LeakyReLU (at your first line). So you just have to do `get_keras_model.add(LeakyReLU())`

Comment: Tried that as well. It is still throwing the same error.  
ValueError: Unknown activation function: LeakyReLU

Comment: I think the part of my function for adding LeakyReLU to the model is not getting executed at all. It is directly dismissing it as not found without checking the if condition in the function

Comment: You seem to call your `get_keras_model()` at the beginning of your second method, ignoring what is done to the model after that. The `get_keras_model.add(tf.layers.leakyReLU())` is very odd also, it should be `model.add(tf.layers.leakyReLU())`.

Comment: I updated my answer. Tell me if it works then.

Comment: Tried the new code, now it says: AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Yes it makes sense. The only way I can think of, without major editing, is to handle the donctition in your other method. I updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233359/discussion-between-prasinus-albus-and-whole-brain).